# How to setup accessibility for all table cell contents in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, accessibility

I setup the accessibility for the table cell  successfully. But I have two cases:

If I set the accessibility to `self.containerview`, I need to tap on each element and it gives the voice over for each element.

If I set the accessibility to `self`, the voice over is reading the cell content except the image view. Somehow, the voiceover is neglecting the image view and is only reading the uilabels.

This is how I setup the accessibility:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
 [UIViewController makeViewAccessible:self]; //tried self.containerView, If i put self here, voice over is not reading the imageview
 }
```

and the method:

```
 +(void)makeViewAccessible:(UIView *)view {
for(UIView *subview in [view subviews]){
     if([subview isMemberOfClass:[UIView class]]){
        [self makeStaticViewAccessible:subview];
    }else if([subview isMemberOfClass:[UILabel class]]){
        [subview setIsAccessibilityElement:YES];
        [subview setAccessibilityTraits:UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText];
    }  else if([subview isMemberOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
        [subview setIsAccessibilityElement:YES];
        [subview setAccessibilityTraits:UIAccessibilityTraitImage];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should disable accessibility of `self` and `self.containerView.`
 **Ex:** `[self.containerView setIsAccessibilityElement:NO]`

Now you can set accessibility of each subviews, by using your custom method`(+(void)makeStaticViewAccessible:(UIView *)view)`.